# how to implement placeholder tokens in drupal

Tags: drupal

How can one insert a token into a textarea?

There is a token insert module, but that does not have a stable version out yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taken from drupal.org

```
hook_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array())
```

**This function should return a keyed array of placeholders, and their replacement values. $type contains the current context -- 'node', 'user', 'global', etc. $object contains the specific node, user, etc. that should be used as the basis for the replacements. Only generate and return replacement tokens when $type is something that your module can really deal with. That helps keep things speedy and avoid needlessly
searching for jillions of replacement tokens. The $options array can contain additional options (exact use is dynamic and not easily documented).**

For example:

```
function my_user_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array()) {
  if ($type == 'user') {
    $user = $object;
    $tokens['name']      = $user->name;
    $tokens['mail']      = $user->mail;
    return $tokens;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: For D6, this functionality depends on token.module. Drupal 7 has generic token handling built in, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7. The token module does still exist there, but only to provide an UI and additional tokens which did not make it into core.

Comment: This code is for *providing* tokens, not actually performing token replacement.